# Not showing a red rectangle box on Face

Tags: java, android, face

```
    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    bitmap = new BitmapFactory().decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.danish,options);
    imageHeight = image_1.getHeight();
    imageWidth = image_1.getWidth();

    face = new Face[numberofFaces];
    faceDetector = new FaceDetector(imageWidth,imageHeight,numberofFaces);

    foundfaces = faceDetector.findFaces(bitmap,face);

    if (foundfaces > 0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Found Face",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"No face found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

    drawCanvas(canvas);

}

private void drawCanvas(Canvas canvas) {


    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,0,0,null);

    for(int i=0;i<foundfaces;i++)
    {
        Face faces = face[i];
        PointF midPoint = new PointF();
        faces.getMidPoint(midPoint);
        eyedistance = faces.eyesDistance();
        canvas.drawRect((int)midPoint.x - eyedistance,(int) midPoint.y - eyedistance, (int)midPoint.x + eyedistance,(int)midPoint.y + eyedistance,paint);
    }

    Toast.makeText(this,"Eye Distance: "+eyedistance,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

I am doing a face detection project and detecting a face via Android Face Libraryyy.... this code of face detection is giving me a positive output of eye distance and things like that but not showing a rectangle box on a face Can anyone help regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of coding your own drawCanvas, simply override the `onDraw` method of your custom view.

In this method, check if you have Faces found. If so, loop through them, and use the `canvas` given as a parameter of the `onDraw` function to draw your bitmap on each face.

To trigger the `onDraw` method on your view, simply call `this.invalidate` once you have found Faces

You could use something like the class as follow.

Usage will be :

```
MyView view = (MyView) findViewById(R.id.myview); //id in your xml
view.setImageResource(R.id.your_image);
view.computeFaces();
```

And here's the call `MyView` :

```
public class MyView extends View {
  private Face[] foundFaces;

  public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public void computeFaces() {
  //In here, do the Face finding processing, and store the found Faces in the foundFaces variable.
    if (numberOfFaces> 0) {
      this.invalidate();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if ((foundFaces != null) && (foundFaces.length > 0)) {
        for (Face f : foundFaces) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(
              //your square bitmap,
              //x position of the face,
              //y position of the face,
              //your define paint);
        }
    }
  }
}
```